# Evaluate Scope in JavaScript Example

Tags: javascript, scope

Looking at this "CoffeeScript - Accelerated JavaScript Development" example:

```
(function() {
  var age, reincarnate;

  age = 99;

  reincarnate = function() {
    var age;
    age = 0;
    console.log("inner age:", age);
    return age;
  };

  reincarnate();

  console.log("I am " + age + " years old");

}).call(this);
```

Why does `age` print out to `99` in this example?

`reincarnate`, a closure (as I understand), has access to `age`. Why doesn't its action change the `age` to 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `reincarnate()` contains:

```
var age;
age = 0;
```

It redeclares the `age` variable in its own scope. Subsequently, the name `age` refers to the "new" variable, not to the captured one.

Omitting the `var` keyword would have resulted in the captured `age` variable being modified.